# Difference in hog descriptor computed on color images in Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I've computed the [`HOGDescriptor`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html) on a color image and found different results in Python and C++, the opencv version, HOG parameters and image being the same on both.
There is a startling difference between the HOG descriptors computed in C++ and Python on the default BGR image

[image: First 100 values of BGR HOG Descriptor in C++]
[image: First 100 values of BGR HOG Descriptor in Python]

There is again, a startling difference between the HOG descriptors computed in C++ and Python on the default BGR2RBG image. However, C++ seems to follow the recommended (by Dalal, Triggs) way of computing the HOG as the max of all three channels, as is proved by the fact that BGR and RGB image has the same HOG descriptor, but Python does not

[image: First 100 values of RGB HOG Descriptor in C++]
[image: First 100 values of RGB HOG Descriptor in Python]

The grayscale versions of the image, however, show similar (**but not same**) descriptor values.

[image: First 100 values of GRAY HOG Descriptor in C++ and Python]

HOG parameters:

```
cv::HOGDescriptor hogDescriptor;
hogDescriptor.blockSize = cv::Size(8, 8);
hogDescriptor.cellSize = cv::Size(4, 4);
hogDescriptor.blockStride = cv::Size(4, 4);
hogDescriptor.nbins = 9;
hogDescriptor.signedGradient = true;
hogDescriptor.winSize = cv::Size(72, 72);
```

My question is, why is there such a large difference between the C++ and Python implementations even though Python is just a wrapper for the C++ version?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Difference in opencv hog descriptor computed in python and c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488186/difference-in-opencv-hog-descriptor-computed-in-python-and-c), same User too.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews. Although both questions seem similar, they bring up different issues in calculating HOGs: the behavior of opencv on calculating HOGs on different color images in the same language and calculating HOGs on the same colorspace in different languages

Comment: Saying the `cv2` Python module is "just a wrapper" is a little false. The original `cv` module was, but `cv2` uses numpy types for calculations for example, so things will in general have small differences (no idea if that's the actual problem here tho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution for grayscale images. The Python wrapper code for the HOG descriptor initializes the `gammaCorrection` flag as `False` as opposed to `True` in C++. Manually setting the flags as True or False for both results in the exact same values for C++ and Python on grayscale images. 
[image]

However, the problem presists for color images.

[image]

My best guess is that, like the `gammaCorrection` flag discrepancy, there is something similar going on in the Python wrapper.